# How to set ttk.TNotebook active color

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

this is my code:

```
import tkinter as tk
style = ttk.Style()
style.map("TRadiobutton",
        foreground=[('pressed', 'red'), ('active', 'red'), ('selected', 'red')],
        background=[('pressed', '!disabled', 'red'), ('active', '#ffa500')],)
style.map("TEntry", background=[('selected','red'),('disabled', 'yellow')])
style.map("TEntry", foreground=[('active','red'), ('selected','red'),('readonly','yellow')])
style.map("TEntry", fieldbackground=[('disabled', 'red')])
style.map('TNotebook.Tab', fieldbackground= [('active', 'red')]      )
```

But it dosn't work as it has.

Only the Radiobutton is working, the others don't. What I'm doing wrong?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: "doesn't work as it has". Does that mean it used to work and just suddenly stopped, without you changing anything? The code you posted doesn't even create a notebook, so how do you know it's not working?

Answer (score 0):

you are right. It's not the whole code.
My problem is, that the radiobuttons are colored, but the Notebook.Tab and the TEntry are not colored as expected.

Comment: This post isn't an actual attempt at answering the question. Please note [StackOverflow doesn't work like a discussion forum](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), it is a Q&A site where every post is either a question or an answer to a question. Posts can also have [comments](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) - small sentences like this one - that can be used to critique or request clarification from an author. This should be either a comment or a [new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask)